# how to plot custom waypoints in google maps v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to plot custom waypoints in google maps v3 ,where i have an array of custom waypoints in code behind . which i need to send it to  javascript and plot the waypoints.
Please help me.

Thanks:
pramod

Comment: What do your "custom waypoints" look like (are they coordinates or addresses)?  How many of them are there?  What does your code to handle them look like?

Answer (score 0):

Just loop over them and create a marker for each:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker